# boost::asio::async_write gets to the other side with a \0 started string

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm not a boost expert and I'm trying to use boost::asio. All was well until something I did messed things up. Unfortunately I'm not sure what have I done... =P

Here's what happens:

I have a server which is a C++ Builder Application that opens a socket where my client application (Visual Studio C++ DLL) connects.

When I try to write something to the socket I get no errors but the server receives the string like this: "\0SomeText". I have no idea where does that \0 come from.

Below some code that might clear things up:

```
    void CometClient::SendCommand()
{
    if (socket_.is_open())
    {
        TCommands::iterator it = pending_commands.begin();
        while (it != pending_commands.end())
        {
            std::vector<char> vctCommand;
            vctCommand.assign((*it).begin(), (*it).end());
            vctCommand.push_back('\n');
            boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<char> > ptr_command = boost::make_shared<std::vector<char> > (vctCommand);

            boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer( *ptr_command ) ,
                boost::bind(&CometClient::handle_write_request, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error, ptr_command )
                );
            it = pending_commands.erase(it);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        // Something
    }
}

void CometClient::handle_write_request(const boost::system::error_code& err, boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<char> > command)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        std::vector<char> * ptr = command.get();
        boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, response_, "\n",
            boost::bind(&CometClient::handle_read_content, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
        // Something
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here`s what I have after janm answer:

```
    void CometClient::SendCommand()
{
    // bConnected tells me if the server has already answered me and Connected just tells me if the socket is open (will change in the near future)
    if (Connected() && pending_commands.size() && bConnected)
    {
        std::vector<char> vctCommand;
        std::string sCommand(pending_commands.front().c_str());
        pending_commands.pop_front();
        vctCommand.assign(sCommand.begin(), sCommand.end());
        vctCommand.push_back('\n');
        boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<char> > ptr_command = boost::make_shared<std::vector<char> > (vctCommand);

        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer( *ptr_command, sCommand.length() ) ,
            boost::bind(&CometClient::handle_write_request, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error, ptr_command )
            );
    }
    else
    {
        // Something
    }
}

void CometClient::handle_write_request(const boost::system::error_code& err, boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<char> > command)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        std::vector<char> * ptr = command.get();
        boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, response_, "\n",
            boost::bind(&CometClient::handle_read_content, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        SendCommand();
    }
    else
    {
        // Something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating multiple concurrent calls to `async_write()`. These calls are not guaranteed to be atomic or in sequence. The reason is that `async_write()` is implemented in terms of multiple calls to `async_write_some()`, the caller must make sure that there is only one `async_write()` in progress as any one time.

A better approach would be to dequeue the first command from your queue and start up the next write in the completion handler. That could be a cause of a spurious byte you don't expect.

The other thing to check is that your vectors really contain what you think they contain. Check this using a debugger or emitted log output.

Comment: You were right, I was making multiple concurrent calls to async_write(). Unfortunately, fixing that didn`t solve the problem... I`m still sending that \0 in the begging of the string.... any other ideas? And my vector does contain the right data...

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this here just for the record.

One of the problems was exactly what janm said, I was in fact doing multiple concurrent calls to async_write. I`ve fixed that and it wasn`t enough. Talking to a friend we've discoverd that I was sending the wrong size for my strings, so I've changed the code a bit and below I'm pasting the final aproach, which works. =)

What I've learned:

- Be carefull not to make multiple concurrent calls to async_write
- Pay attention in order to send the correct number of bytes
- Remember to keep buffer contents alive until the async_write call ends

Thanks a lot @janm

```
void CometClient::AddCommand(std::string _command)
{
    pending_commands.push_back(_command);
    ExecuteCommands();
}

void CometClient::ExecuteCommands()
{
    if (Conectado() && pending_commands.size())
    {
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer( pending_commands.front(), pending_commands.front().length() ) ,
            boost::bind(&CometClient::handle_write_request, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error)
            );
    }
    else
    {
        // Something
    }
}

void CometClient::handle_write_request(const boost::system::error_code& err)
{
    if (!err)
    {
        pending_commands.pop_front();
        boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, response_, "\n",
            boost::bind(&CometClient::handle_read_content, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        ExecuteCommands();
    }
    else
    {
        // Something
    }
}
```